# Merging tables in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I stumbled into [Ajedi32](https://superuser.com/users/83682/ajedi32)'s formula for merging two tables at [How do I merge two tables in Excel that have identical columns?](https://superuser.com/questions/537339/how-do-i-merge-two-tables-in-excel-that-have-identical-columns)

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Table1,ROWS(A$2:A2),COLUMN(A2)), IFERROR(INDEX(Table2,ROWS(A$2:A2)-ROWS(Table1),COLUMN(A2)), "-"))
```

And I have a question.

Although this works great for just 2 tables, is it possible to make it work for more than 2 tables? I have spent some time working with your formula and I can't seem to find a way to make it work with more than 2 tables.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks